# Unity freezes when adjusting the script to many objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on dropping the ball through Unity and getting the coordinates of the ball. Two things were applied: a script for physical action and a script for dropping a ball. I don't think there's a problem with the operation of these two codes. Because there's no problem when I apply the script to one ball. By the way, when the number of balls is increased to 100, Unity stops. I brought the part of the entire code that I think will be problematic:

```
    //Debug.Log(transform.position.ToString());   
    Debug.Log(dir);
    filepath = dir + num + transform.position.ToString();
    Debug.Log(filepath);
    File.Create(filepath);
}
```

I think there's a problem with the part which creates the file. I fixed that part like this:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath);                     
fs.Dispose();
```

After applying this, there was a slight movement when I played, but then it stopped again. I have to force myself to end through the work manager to use my Unity. Will I be able to get help? Since I am a beginner, I would be more grateful if you could explain it in easy words. My project version is 2018.4.36f1.

Comment: This is code in the C# language, not the UnityScript language. Please do not add irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Llama Oh I thought Unity Script and C# were the same. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I see. UnityScript is a Javascript-derived language that was deprecated a few years ago in favour of C#.

Comment: just to extend @Llama 's comments ..... which you can read yourself in the tag description of [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info)

Comment: What is your use case...? **WHY** do you want to create a file for each object (and then leave it empty)? And if it is really needed why not use **asnyc** FileIO? FileIO is one of the most expensive operations on any OS .. so usually you want to be sure it is not done on the UI main thread ... (and btw `string name = this.gameObject.ToString();` equals simply using the property `MonoBehaviour.name` ^^)

Comment: I think you rather want to have one big central container class storing all the information of your objects and then serialize it **once** into a **single file** e.g. as **JSON**

Comment: @derHugo I'm doing an "experiment" which I drop the ball and save its location. I don't necessarily have to make it into multiple single files.That part seems to be overloaded, and I used it without recognizing that it was a costly method. Your advice is very precious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It freezes because you are trying to do a lot of works just in one frame. It doesn't make sense why would you like to create a file for each position and gameobject. Maybe you are trying to log something?

If you are trying to log something, I would suggest you log to a simple file, not multiple files. It's not efficient for your application as well as for your debugging time.

For logging, you can use [String Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0). Initialize your StringBuilder object in Start/Awake Method. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`. Each time you want to add something to your log, do `sb.Append("A log");`.

Now for saving, you can save it `OnDisable()` or `OnApplicationQuit()`. To save -

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("FILE_PATH", sb.ToString());
```

I hope that serves.

Comment: Also having an if checking the same thing in hundreds of entities, every frame I am afraid, should make an avoidable impact on the performance