# Unity stops though code edited with String Builder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing an experiment of dropping a ball from Unity. There was no problem with the script when only **one** was dropped. But when I drop about **100 balls**, Unity keeps stopping.

```
    //Debug.Log(transform.position.ToString());   
    Debug.Log(dir);
    filepath = dir + num + transform.position.ToString();
    Debug.Log(filepath);
    File.Create(filepath);
}
```

At first, I operated Unity using the above script.

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath);                     
fs.Dispose();
```

Also, I changed like the above, however, still unity freezed.

Finally, With several advices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734331/unity-freezes-when-adjusting-the-script-to-many-objects?noredirect=1#comment123263297_69734331), I wrote a new script like this:

```
        //Debug.Log(transform.position.ToString());   
        Debug.Log(dir);
        filepath = dir + num + transform.position;
        Debug.Log(filepath);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, name.ToString());
    }
```

Nevertheless, Unity stops again after unity starts to operate for a certain period of time. So is this no longer a script issue? I don't think it's a problem with RAM because my desktop is using 16GB RAM. I continued to modify the code, but it still seems to stop, so I want to get the correct code or solution. I don't have to have multiple files. It can be a single file, so I want it to work.

Comment: The content of the question and the heading are not syncing with each other, seems like you need to explain the problem in detail or with relevant information. I couldn't see any code related to **dropping a ball**, leave alone **dropping 100 balls**. Unity performs some tasks, when you come back to Unity Editor from IDE after making a change in the code, I hope that is not the issue you referring to here. I am not the downvoter yet.

Comment: Well the answer about the StringBuilder in your duplicate question only solves a minimum issue ... The main issue still is your huge FileIO ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are implementing it wrong. I told you to save to file in `OnDisable()` or `OnApplicationQuit()` method, not each time you write.

Here is what you can do -

```
public class Logger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string logFilePath = "C:/log.txt";
    public StringBuilder sb;

    public static Logger self;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (self == null)
            self = this;
        else
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    // it will be called when game quits 
    // for editor, when playmode stops
    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        // save file 
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(logFilePath, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

This your class that will be attached to each ball -

```
public class YourClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
        {
            // gameObject name
            string goName = this.gameObject.ToString();

            // expected output - AObject (1) : (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) 
            // Later if you ever need, you can read all lines and split by ':' 
            Logger.self?.sb.Append($"{goName} : {transform.position.ToString()}\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that is okay now.

Comment: Still StringBuilder only has a minimal impact ... the main sue is the FileIO itself ...

Comment: I agree. But this time, it will be called at the end of the game life-cycle, will it impact Game Experience?

Comment: Thank you again for good code. I'm trying to execute your code. However, `The type or namespace name 'StringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` error occured in the `public StringBuilder sb;` part. I connected these codes together and made them into a single file. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: You have to add `using System.Text` in order to use `StringBuilder` class. And yes, you should put them in separate class, so you can add Logger and YourClass in different gameobject.

Comment: @SrejonKhan Then, for one ball, is it right to apply those two classes to two different files? Or do I have to make it into one file? I understood what the code functions, but I didn't understand how to generate the file to be correct. I'm a beginner at Unity, and I've always understood that C# works only in objects. So I'd like to ask if it's right to make and apply each class in two files per ball.

Comment: Attach `Logger.cs` to a single different object, not to a ball. And your BallClass will be attached to each object (ball).

Comment: @SrejonKhan I played it thanks to you. However, it halted again...... It works several seconds and the unityr stops. May be not the code, unity problem?

Comment: Seems sus to me. Are you doing other expensive work? Or can you do profiling? Additionally, if Unity crash, you can see the log (please search in google for Unity Editor Log Location).

Comment: @SrejonKhan depends .. if as a user I am trying to close an app but instead it freezes for quite some time I'll be quite sure to not open that app anymore ;)

Comment: True. A bit of off-topic. How would you handle that? Make a Background Thread and do saving work on that thread?

Comment: @derHugo Regardless of the method, I just need to get the result value in the form I initially specified. I'm trying, but I'm a beginner, so I may not understand everything you say. I sincerely thank you for your help. And, I tried running the profiler, but the profiler stops as soon as it runs. So, first of all, I checked only the edit log and uploaded the last part of my article. Please check the link. There is a log about mono developer in the middle, but before installing it, there was already a pause error and I already deleted it now.

Comment: @SrejonKhan What I want to say to you is the same as above. Deep gratitude.

Comment: @EmmaLim Crash Log is most probably in `AppData\LocalLow\Unity\CrashReports`. Could you check? And what other functionality do you run for the game? Especially for balls? Any expensive work?

Comment: @SrejonKhan Sadly, there was no crash report even though I checked your route and google. I think the related logs are all I uploaded. Additionally, I have applied another script about air resistance to the ball. Therefore, two scripts were currently applied to one ball. I also uploaded the air resistance script in my article. Maybe this is the problem? But there was still no problem when I dropped one ball with these two scripts. There is a problem when there are 100 balls. I'll check the comment about 7hours later because of my night time. Thank you so much

Comment: @EmmaLim what about that script you add to ball? Anything else on `Update()`?

Comment: @SrejonKhan Only two files, the air resistance file I just uploaded and the other file I achieved in this answer, are applied to the ball. Nothing else has been applied. It's exactly what I uploaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238623/discussion-between-srejon-khan-and-emma-lim).